# Jenkins pipeline sh: always use pipefail

Tags: shell, jenkins, pipe, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to configure `sh` step to always act as if `set -o pipefail` was set?

This bug took me days to discover... since I assumed this would be the default setting.

Comment: I don't think there is one without you wrapping every execution either in a shell script or method yourself.

Comment: @mkobit actually, I've discovered that `sh` uses the same session to send commands, which has quite a few other adverse side-effects... but, ultimately, it's enough to do `sh "set -o pipefail"` in the beginning of your script to get this to work for the entirety of the script... unless it gets interrupted and continues execution on a different slave :) As if life wasn't interesting enough without this little gotcha!